# Why does my function work incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for not giving a clear title, because I don't know why my script doesn't work.

```
var all=[]; 
function People(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.func=function(){alert(this.name)}; 
    all.push(this);
};
var person1=new People('Peter');
for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){
    var newBtn=document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(newBtn);
    newBtn.type='button';
    newBtn.value=all[i].name;

    newBtn.onclick=all[i].func; // why doesn't is say "Peter" when I click the button ?
};
```

Btw, is there a better way to achieve my goal: creat some objects; with each object, creat a button; when a button is clicked, do some function.

Comment: @KirenSiva Usually a good question to ask, but no need to shout it. :)

Comment: @KirenSiva He didn't say it's throwing an error, he said it's not alerting `Peter` when he clicks the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are clicking on the button, the context of the event handler (`this` variable) becomes the button itself. You can check it simply putting `console.log(this)` inside a `func`.
I would recommend the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){
    var newBtn=document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(newBtn);
    newBtn.type='button';
    newBtn.value=all[i].name;

    newBtn.onclick=all[i].func.bind(all[i]);
};
```

Using `bind()` you explicitly push the desired context into the function. 
[**More on bind.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: +1 Yes, I just did that, added console.log(this), came to answer... and you beat me XD

Comment: @Artyom Neustroev Thank you, your suggestion works fine. I will try to replace (this.name) with (name) first, as others suggested. If I get any error, I'll have a closer look at bind()

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/NCTMD/1/**

**JS:-**

```
var all=[]; 
function People(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.func=function(){alert(name)}; 
    all.push(this);
};
var person1=new People('Peter');
for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){
    var newBtn=document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(newBtn);
    newBtn.type='button';
    newBtn.value=all[i].name;

    newBtn.onclick=all[i].func; // why doesn't is say "Peter" when I click the button ?
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try pushing the person objects to all array

```
var all=[]; 
function People(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.func=function(){alert(this.name)}; 
};


var person1=new People('Peter');

//push the person objects

all.push(person1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
this.func=function(){alert(this.name)};
```

replace

```
this.name
```

to just

```
name
```

, since you're calling it out of scope, your this is different (it's the button - object HTMLInputElement).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var all=[]; 
    function People(name){
        this.name=name;
        this.func=function(){alert(name)}; 
        all.push(this);
    };
    var person1=new People('Peter');

    for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){
        var newBtn=document.createElement('input');
        newBtn.type='button';
        newBtn.value=all[i].name;
        newBtn.onclick=all[i].func;
        document.body.appendChild(newBtn);

    }
});
```

there some minor mistake. document.body always pass null. For that script run between document.ready function for get document.body value.